# Android-Bluetooth: How to connect with bluetooth to a A2DP Profile to stream music over the speaker?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, a2dp

I want to connect from my phone to a bluetooth module with a A2DP profile. And then I want that the speaker of this module plays the music which I have on my phone.

I tried this example: [A2DP Bluetooth Example](http://derivedcode.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/connecting-to-a-bluetooth-a2dp-device-from-android/)

But when I run it, it gives me the error: **Could not bind to Bluetooth A2DP Service**

What can I do against this? Or can anyone give me another simple example for it?